# JMeter HTTP request showing Invalid credential and not getting Pass

Tags: jmeter

I am testing a site having login page and then some blogs on which we can comment/post.
I first login to the site and then select a blog and make a comment on that blog.
I am able to pass the login request and select blog request but comment on the blog request showing error Invalid credential.

**Here is the response message:**

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2014-09-17 12:41:42 IST
Load time: 9
Latency: 9
Size in bytes: 286
Headers size in bytes: 286
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 403
Response message: Invalid credentials
```

**Response headers:**

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Invalid credentials
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
X-Telligent-Evolution: 8.0.0.37997
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 17 Sep 2014 07:11:42 GMT
Content-Length: 0


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

**And this is the request data:**

```
POST http://192.xx.xx.61/TelligentCommunity/api.ashx/v2/comments.json
```

**POST data:**

```
Body=This+is+the+sample+post+by+Arjun&ContentId=c6bc2886-1fcb-46a4-8120-e344b8d8e4a1&ContentTypeId=f7d226ab-d59f-475c-9d22-
```

**Cookie Data:**

```
AuthorizationCookie=71710e44-7ba7-4af7-b390-6ae81cdec229; .Telligent.Evolution=F426475F7F35ED7250E97697BCC3DE0147BD3D15C494681A9C188922459CC698DD6F6A0CA77D61E2D5C6A56A5239B338B8DC484DAB6A4073B69F9F9139500867A843A9EB39D217825C47672E1B5165214A990F8E9CF519ED6159591B510967F84F6810CBCC4466E0DA5E37D03AB0E341A6DA0970861A2F58EE873E168D1A851D9B956033B10C9856D680FC6AC5736F961631BDD1A66EE89024020BF55A8422B24A485311C87C5074F2507E4FFA9EFBADC36B0DCBC051965ACE32EDA2B5607FEBDE17F0C2F486A42E05680FD90F30494B
```

**Request Headers:**

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Rest-Authorization-Code: 7a24113f-2a71-428b-80c7-57234aac67c1
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
DNT: 1
Pragma: no-cache
Authorization-Code: 7a24113f-2a71-428b-80c7-57234aac67c1
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://192.xx.xx.61/TelligentCommunity/certification/b/90days2mcsa/archive/2014/09/12/how-to-win-by-contributing-to-the-mcp-community
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 123
Host: 192.xx.xx.61
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure that your login request is successful? How do you know? ASP.NET applications use dynamic parameters like [viewstate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) or [eventvalidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation(v=vs.110).aspx) and they need to be extracted from the previous response and added to the next one. See [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide for details.
2. Looking into `api` and `json` URL bits I would expect that `Content-Type` header should be `application/json`. I would suggest adding a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) as a child of the request which posts a blog comment and configure it to send above Content-Type.
3. This `Authorization-Code` header value: is it something you recorded or it came from correlation? If first you need to pass the correct value as well.

Comment: Yes it is related to Authorization-Code mistake. Now i am able to by pass the error 4.3-Invalid Credential.

Comment: But now there is another problem. when i call http://192.xx.xx.61/TelligentCommunity/api.ashx/v2/comments.json , It passes three parameter with request body, ContentId, ContentTypeId. In which ContentId and ContentTypeId are dynamic and generating at runtime whith in this request. How can i pass dynamic value to these.

Comment: Try searching for them in page source and work around like Authorization-Code, unfortunately I know nothing about Telligent Community hence cannot help further